# Get constructor parameter from JSON, inside the constructor?

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, fs

I have a constructor for a object. Since the parameters for it s creation are fixed, I have stored them in a JSON file as a array, and hoped I could make the constructor take the parameters from that file.

Even if reading a JSON file is fast, I d prefer not to, and thought that I could do this:

```
//test.json:
[
    {"foo": "L", "bar": 120000},
    {"foo": "T", "bar": 1000},
    {"foo": "D",    "bar": 1000}
]
```

So now, in my object, I just have to parse the JSON, and create the object from it, I ve thought it would be as simple as:

```
//test.js
var fs = require('fs'),
    tests = [];

function Test(id) {
    this.foo = tests[id].foo;
    this.bar = tests[id].bar;
}

function print() {
    console.log(this);
}

module.exports = Test;
Test.prototype.print = print;

fs.readFile('./tests.json', function (err, data) {
    if (err) {
        console.log('Error reading tests.json\n' + err);
        throw err;
        return ;
    }
    tests = JSON.parse(data);
});
```

But when I try to use it:

```
var Test = require('./test.js'),
    t = new Test(0);

t.print();
```

node throw a undefined error on `tests` in `test.js`.

The solution I can see are all impratical:

- Parse the JSON inside the constructor. It would either block the event loop or make the constructor asynchronous, which is bad either way.
- Parse the JSON from outside, and make a simple class constructor. That would be impratical since that object is used in multiple module, some of whom are themselves object, and as such would need to get that JSON as parameters...

What am I missing? Is this pattern possible, or should I start again and find another solution?

Comment: Your problem is not about the constructor, it's just that `tests` is asynchronously created. Make that a  `readFileSync`.

Comment: @Bergi: I can t believe I didn t saw that... I ll accept ShanShan answer's because it s right too, and learned me something too, but will use your solution since I can still do error checking with a try/catch.

Comment: `require()` throws errors too (not found, syntax error...) :)

Comment: @DrakaSAN: Actually `require` is superior to `readFileSync` in case of JSON - you'll only need it for custom file formats.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It throws `undefined error` because `fs.readFile()` is async so `tests` is not initialized yet when you try to read it.

You don't need to manually read your json file and parse it, you can require it and you'll get a fine object:

```
var tests = require('./tests.json'); // << make sure the path is ok
console.log(tests);
```